# UIPageViewController Page Number on Toolbar

Tags: objective-c, ios

I have a PageViewApplication that I am writing and I am oh so nearly there! but I have a problem getting the page number to show as the title of a button I have in a toolbar.

The toolbar is activated when a user taps once on the image in the pageviewcontroller and on this toolbar is a button, which I am told, is the best way to display the page number.

I have written the following where `_currentPageNumber` is an Integer of the current Index

```
NSString *strTotalPages = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d", NrOfImages];
_pageNumbering.title = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d / %@", _currentPageNumber, strTotalPages];
```

My issue is where to place this as at the moment it is just showing 0

Any help would be great

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I use this function and is working fine

```
- (NSUInteger)indexOfViewController:(LeafletPageContentViewController *)viewController {   

return [self.modelArray indexOfObject:viewController.dataObject]; }
```

modelArray is the array with the data of each view

Then, when I want to know the current index use this

```
ClassOfMyViewController *currentViewController = [self.pageViewController.viewControllers objectAtIndex:0];


NSUInteger retreivedIndex = [self indexOfViewController:currentViewController];
```

Answer (score 0):

If you're changing the title of a button on a toolbar then you will need to remove/re-create and add the button to the toolbar as it isn't quite as simple as just changing the title of the button with a string value.

Essentially redrawing it should solve the issue.

Comment: THanks for this is there a way to show the current page number on this toolbar when it is called?

Comment: When you redraw it you can simply do something like this:
NSString *string = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"Page: %d", pageController.currentPage];

It may be slightly different than "currentPage" but I can't verify quite yet.

Answer (score 0):

I struggled with this problem, but the pageViewController doesn't provide a method to retrieve the current page.
So, if you use the method `pageControllerAfterPageController` or `pageControllerBeforePageController` you should get a wrong page number: in fact, if you swipe your finger to change page, but you don't complete the swipe, the page showed remains the same, but your counter show the previous or next page number.

So, you can try to use `viewDidLoad` method of your `contentViewController` for update the counter and the button !